# How do I solve error 503 when load Excel phpspreadsheet?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, phpspreadsheet

The server (maddogdomains) throws error 503, when the phpspreasheet plugin loads an Excel of 22MB and more than 40,000 records, see line 10 ($reader->load($inputFileName)) of the following code:

```
$data = array(
    'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
);
$inputFileType = 'Xls';
$inputFileName =$data['upload_data']['full_path'];

$cache = new FilesystemCache();
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings::setCache($cache);
$reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
```

I have increased memory_limit and all the resources in the php.ini and the 503 error persists. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of time spent by PHPSpreadsheet to read the file.

Try to put `set_time_limit(0);` at top of your script

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried that function and error 503 still appears. I think it's a server problem (maddogdomains), because on my local machine that error does not happen